# cannot set state on component that has not mounted bug

Tags: reactjs, api

I am in the middle of working on a pretty simple app and I got this error I have not seen before and none of the previous threads solved for me either. My code is below, please note my app is not done at all I am just not sure why I am getting this error. My best guess is that I am initializing state wrong but I have already changed some items around to no avail:

```
WIP code:

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';


const api = axios.create({
baseURL: 'https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search'

})

class App extends Component {

  state ={
    search: []
  }

  constructor(){
    super();
    api.get('/').then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({search: res.data})
    })

}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Can't `setState` in constructor, use `componentDidMount` (or any *other* lifecycle function).

[constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)

```
class App extends Component {
  state ={
    search: []
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    api.get('/').then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({search: res.data})
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Also GET request can resolve *after* component unmounts, use `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle function.

Comment: @PraveenSaboji Did you intend to leave this as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, you can define state in the constructor and make the initial call to the API on mount

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      catPictures: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    api.get('/').then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({catPictures: res.data})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense to me. I have not called an api with the hooks other than useState before -

Comment: Just wanted to expand on this comment so you're clear on the terminology: there are two ways you could write this code, either as a class Component (with extends Component, constructor, setState, render, etc.) or as a functional component (with hooks and useState). Make sure not to confuse these lifecycle methods (like componentDidMount) with hooks, since they're very different. Lots of explanations out there if you search for 'Component vs. Functional React'

Comment: Thank you - I know the difference, I am more familiar with hooks and using State I just wanted to try to solve it another way

Answer (score 0):

You should not use api call inside constructor, since it's meant for only class initialization, since the component haven't mounted and you're trying access it from constructor you got that error , use API call in componentWillmount if you want to call api before component mounts